# Android EditText watcher limit by time for API call?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, textwatcher

I have an Edit text which I use to observe the changes for an auto updating search page. On each character entered, the watcher is fired so for a search query like `apple`, the query is fired as,

```
D/debug: a
D/debug: ap
D/debug: app
D/debug: appl
D/debug: apple
```

So i added a delay of `2s` with timer, and the log looks like

```
D/debug: apple
D/debug: apple
D/debug: apple
D/debug: apple
D/debug: apple
```

firing it all together at once after `2s`.  Here is my text watcher,

```
search_et.addTextChangedListener( object: TextWatcher{
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        val timer = Timer()
        timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                Log.d("debug", "$s");
            }
        }, 2000)            
    }
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
})
```

What I want to accomplish is to **get the value from EditText once in 2s**, What can I do in this case to get it right?

Comment: Have you tried to put it in onTextChanged instead of afterTextChanged?

Comment: @PraveenSP it behaves the same

Answer (score 2):

Using handler concept we can do this way. By this way we can limit the no. of api calls while implementing search functionality in edit text.

Java:

```
        private Handler textSearchHandler  = new Handler(); //declare it as a global variable
        et_FilterStopsFromListActivity_FilterETxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textSearchHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //It will clear all previous callbacks
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                textSearchHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       callApi();//do whatever you want to do
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);

            }
        });
```

Kotlin:

```
private var textChangedHandler = Handler() // declare it globally.
tie_password.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            textChangedHandler.postDelayed(runnable,2000)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            textChangedHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable)
        }
    })

 var runnable = Runnable {
    callApi() //do whatever you want to do here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a handler for this use case. You are not handling previous query result. you have to discard the previous result and emit a new query.

```
private var runnable: Runnable? = null

private var handler: Handler? = null

private var timeToWait = 2000L //change this one for delay (time in milli)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)
    setListenersForSearch()
}

private fun setListenersForSearch() {

    //Initialize your handler
    handler = Handler()

    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            runnable = Runnable {

                //check if it is not empty then search
                if (etSearch.text.toString().isEmpty().not()) {
                    search(etSearch.text.toString())
                }
            }
            handler?.postDelayed(runnable, timeToWait)
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            //remove call back for old query
            handler?.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        }
    })
}


private fun search(query: String) {
    //hit your API call
}
```